# Wireless Connection wifi not working with intel wireless adpater 8260 and ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 19.10, iwlwifi

I had problems with the wifi, first not being able to access websites. I tried to find a driver and downloaded one at https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless-networking.html for Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260. I copied the file `iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode` to `/lib/firmware/` and rebooted the system. After rebooting I was not able to connect to wifi at all. Entering the right password won't accept it anymore. I am currently connected with a LAN cable. What can I do to have wifi connection?

```
Output of sudo lshw -C network
```

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 3a
       serial: e4:b3:18:e1:e2:22
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-26-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: c8:5b:76:32:3b:7c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.0.178 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:127 memory:f1200000-f121ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wwp0s20f0u2i12
       serial: 96:9e:18:8b:b8:44
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1130]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[   14.802650] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   14.844074] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   14.844078] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   14.844887] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.957558] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[   14.966033] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   14.966669] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   15.049213] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: e4:b3:18:e1:e2:22
[   15.123888] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   15.534768] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   17.625953] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   17.774458] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   17.859110] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

UPDATE

So the wifi works agai but accessing websites still doesn't work.

[This is a screenshot of the askubuntu post when I am trying to access via wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WicBu.png)

For any other command output you need please let me know
Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I edited the post with your requested command

Comment: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Added the command

Comment: I see no problems. Wi-Fi works. Try to remove the firmware you've added.

Comment: I removed it, should I reboot ? Also I am currently connected to lan cable if this might effect the output

Comment: it doesn't affect the output. Yes, reboot and try.

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6 the wifi works but I still can't access websites, i added a screenshot of the problem

Comment: Unplug the Ethernet or disable it.

Comment: It's so weird. It works now! Thank you I am still a little confused but thank you very much @Pilot6

Comment: It is not wierd. When the cable is connected, the system has a default route through the ethernet.

Comment: Okey I understand, glad it works now